# Getting LIMIT syntax error on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, limit

I just want to get the first result of this query but whenever I write down LIMIT. Oracle SQL Developer throws me this error

*ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 7*

Here is the Code:

```
SELECT IDBAR FROM ( SELECT PARRANDEROS.FRECUENTAN.ID_BAR as IDBAR,

COUNT(PARRANDEROS.FRECUENTAN.ID_BAR) c 
FROM PARRANDEROS.FRECUENTAN
GROUP BY PARRANDEROS.FRECUENTAN.ID_BAR
ORDER BY c DESC
) 

LIMIT 1;
```

I've tried this method too:

```
SELECT IDBAR FROM ( SELECT PARRANDEROS.FRECUENTAN.ID_BAR as IDBAR,

COUNT(PARRANDEROS.FRECUENTAN.ID_BAR) c 
FROM PARRANDEROS.FRECUENTAN
GROUP BY PARRANDEROS.FRECUENTAN.ID_BAR
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 1

);
```

Thanks a Lot.

Comment: The error message implies that you are using an Oracle database.  The use of `LIMIT` implies that you are thinking MySQL.  (Never mind that MySQL is owned by Oracle.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jim Garrison. The solution was to use the ROWNUM attribute:

```
SELECT IDBAR FROM ( SELECT PARRANDEROS.FRECUENTAN.ID_BAR as IDBAR, 
COUNT(PARRANDEROS.FRECUENTAN.ID_BAR) c 
FROM PARRANDEROS.FRECUENTAN
GROUP BY PARRANDEROS.FRECUENTAN.ID_BAR
ORDER BY c DESC
) 

WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
```